# Does RCA or "interface connector" (VGA?) offer better video quality?

Tags: conversion, connectors

I'm trying to archive a laser disc as a digital file. My laser disc player (a Pioneer) has 2 video output options: RCA and a 15-pin port labelled "interface connector". The 15 pins are arranged in 2 rows. After researching [video connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_connectors), I think the 15-pin port is VGA. What would be the higher resolution output for creating a digital recording?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'interface connector' is (almost certainly) a serial control port, not a video output. LVD stored composite analog video, so there are no chroma or difference signals available to assist in digitizing the video.

Comment: So for my device, it doesn't matter whether RCA or VGA has better video quality, because my device only has RCA. Is that correct?

Comment: You didn't give us the model number, so I can't be positive, but I've never seen a Pioneer LVD player that had VGA output, and I'm very familiar with the Pioneer 15-pin serial control port, so I'm pretty confident that you don't have VGA (or any component) outputs. That just leaves the RCA composite video out.

Comment: Pioneer CLD-V2400. Looks like you're right. The 15-pin connector is listed under "Other", separate from "Video output" above, leading me to believe that it is not a video output port. I think this confirms your intuition. http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/pio/pe/images/portal/cit_3424/31178828CLDV2400GSpec.pdf